# How can i use Localizer for @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model....) in cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, localization

I want to add mutlipte language my project.I can use localization in cshtml but i cant use it in label tag, displaynamefor tag.

How can i use this?

Comment: Excuse me. I couldnt do it. It didnt work in MyResource.Degisner.cs class.

Comment: add [DataAnnotation localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#dataannotations-localization-2) setup in startup

Answer (score 1):

You could use Display attribute to localize the name:

1.Model:

```
public class Test
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

2.Create resource file named `MyReource.resx` in `Reources` folder:

[image]

3.Create key value in resource file:

**Note:** Modifier on .resx files which is by default set to Internal (in my case it was No code generation). Change it to public in Access Modifier dropdown in the resource file toolbar.

[image]

Also, consider not using special signs in field names as they are a basis for auto-generated C# property names. The field names are converted into C# friendly names and that is why you can end up with inconsistency between name of resource file field and name of auto-generated property. Best to avoid any hyphens `-` or dots `.`.Underscores `_` are fine. You can always look up how the auto-generated properties look like in `resource_file_name.Designer.cs` class under the related resource file.

For Example,You want to display Email property as `Email Address` in the razor,the resource file you need set like below:

[image]

But you could see the `resource_file_name.Designer.cs` is like below:

[image]

4.Modify your model:

```
public class Test
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(MyResource))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = nameof(MyResource.Email_Address), ResourceType = typeof(MyResource))]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

5.Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
         opt =>
         {
             var supportCulteres = new List<CultureInfo>
             {
            new CultureInfo("en"),
            new CultureInfo("fr")
             };
             opt.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
             opt.SupportedCultures = supportCulteres;
             opt.SupportedUICultures = supportCulteres;
         });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model Test
<div>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
</div>
```

Result:

[image]